# Why does Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd have different behaviour from a regular StreamReader.ReadToEnd?

Tags: c#, process, stream

It is currently 2 am and I am confused about why `Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` behaves the way it does. Somehow, it manages to read all the output of a process only once it is completed, rather than only a portion of the standard output (This is expected since the process is run asynchronously.)

`ReadToEnd` is combined with `Process.WaitForExit()`; it is not used on its own. `ReadToEnd` works exactly as documented, but when I try to simulate this using a `MemoryStream`, a `StreamReader`, and an asynchronous `StreamWriter`, `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns immediately, without the same output as written by `StreamWriter`. It's not that `Process.ReadToEnd` doesn't work; I'm just confused about why it does.

Here's the code for the executed file:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args){
   for(int i = 0;i<50;i++){
      Console.WriteLine($"some string {i}");
      Thread.Sleep(arbritraryDelay);
   }
}
```

Here's the test code:

```cs
void ProcessTest(){
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = "executedFile.dll",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();
    //Result is the entire output
}
void SimulatedTest(){
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream()){
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

         Task.Run(() => {
                for(int i = 0;i<50;i++){//Near identical code to the executed file
                    writer.Writeline($"some string {i});
                    Thread.Sleep(arbritraryDelay);
                }
            }
        );
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd(); //different output
    }
}
```

I expected `ProcessTest` to behave the same as `SimulatedTest`, but `ProcessTest` actually captures all output.

Comment: If you check, the [Process.StandardOutput](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,7b00fe2b27d4b60c) is of type `StreamReader` so your question looks caused of your own testing. Probably caused because of having two streams and having some race condition.

Comment: When you open and read a file, Windows will close the stream when you reach the end of file.  c# is really calling a windows method to do the reading.  With Standard Input/Output the application has to close the stream which usually occurs when the application ends.  So Standard input the stream is still open.

Comment: @bradbury9 I'm aware that `Process.StandardOutput` is a `StreamReader`. I'm just curious as to how `Process.StandardOutput` is written so that it works the way it does, as it seems unintuitive based on the way `StreamReader` is supposed to work.

Comment: @jdweng I don't believe that answers anything, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: You question was "ReadToEnd works".It works when you read a file because windows closed the stream/file so there is an end of file.While you have a application running using standard output the stream is still open so there is no end of stream.The application can still add more data to the end of the stream.  Windows a stream has only one pointer which can create issues.Linux is much nicer with two stream pointers.One indicating the input position and on indicate the output position.  Linux the input position can be set to null while the output is still reading.  Windows this cannot be done.